# Creating simple Vagrant provisoner

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, vagrant-provision

I am trying to create a simple Vagrant provisoner that will just run shell scripts. This is what I have so far:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provision "reset", type: "shell", run: "always" do |s|
        s.privileged = false
        s.path = "run.sh"
    end
end
```

So the idea is, when this provisoner is run, it will open the run.sh file as the starting point. That works fine, however, I want inside the `run.sh` file to load other scripts:

**run.sh**

```
for each in scripts/*.sh;
do
    bash $each > /dev/null 2>&1 ;
    rm $each > /dev/null 2>&1 ;
done ;
```

The problem is with `/scripts/` directory. It is located inside the Vagrant folder, where the Vagrantfile is, but the content of `run.sh` is actually copied to the new location and run from there. So the problem is that I can't really access the `scripts` directory. Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you script directory is placed at same location as Vagrantfile, it is automatically shared with the VM under /vagrant directory, you can then reference the full path and replace `scripts/*.sh` by `/vagrant/scripts/*.sh`

you can also create a new sync folder specifically for your scripts directory with something like /scripts and use this new /scripts folder in your bash shell